# How to obtain the state space representation of a computed torque control system?

Tags: control

Assuming I have a system:

$$
a \, \ddot{x}_1 + b \, \ddot{x}_2 + c \,\dot{x_1} + d \,\dot{x_2} + e = u_1 \\
f \, \ddot{x}_1 + g \, \ddot{x}_2 + h \,\dot{x_1} + i \,\dot{x_2} + j = u_2
$$

How would I write this system in state space representation:
$$\dot{x} = Ax+Bu$$
$$y = Cx + Du$$

Usually, I would isolate for $\ddot{x_1}$ or $\ddot{x_2}$, but in this case, they are functions of each other.
Would the only way be to rewrite the dynamics in matrix form after setting new state variables?

Comment: The fact they are coupled makes no difference. You can use your standard methodology. :), set one for x2 and x1 and then solve.

Answer (score 3):

First, isolate the second order from the other terms:

$$
a \, \ddot{x}_1 + b \, \ddot{x}_2 =- c \,\dot{x_1} - d \,\dot{x_2} - e + u_1 \\
f \, \ddot{x}_1 + g \, \ddot{x}_2 = - h \,\dot{x_1} - i \,\dot{x_2} - j + u_2
$$

Then, put it in a matrix form:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\f&g\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}- c \,\dot{x_1} - d \,\dot{x_2} - e + u_1\\- h \,\dot{x_1} - i \,\dot{x_2} - j + u_2\end{matrix}\right].
$$

Supposing $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\f&g\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is invertible, we can left multiply both sides by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\f&g\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}$:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\f&g\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\f&g\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\f&g\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}- c \,\dot{x_1} - d \,\dot{x_2} - e + u_1\\- h \,\dot{x_1} - i \,\dot{x_2} - j + u_2\end{matrix}\right].
$$

Thus, we get:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]
=
{1\over ag-bf}
\left[\begin{matrix}g&-b\\-f&a\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}- c \,\dot{x_1} - d \,\dot{x_2} - e + u_1\\- h \,\dot{x_1} - i \,\dot{x_2} - j + u_2\end{matrix}\right],
$$

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]
=
{1\over ag-bf}
\left[\begin{matrix}(bh-gc)\dot{x_1}+(bi-gd)\dot{x_2}+(bj-je)\\
(fc-ah)\dot{x_1}+(fd-ai)\dot{x_2} + (fe-aj)\end{matrix}\right]
+{1\over ag-bf}
\left[\begin{matrix}
 g&-b\\
-f&a
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{matrix}\right].
$$

Using auxiliary variables:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}\alpha\dot{x_1}+\beta\dot{x_2}+\gamma\\
\delta\dot{x_1}+\epsilon\dot{x_2} + \zeta\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
 \eta&\theta\\
\iota&\kappa
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{matrix}\right].
$$

Here, $\gamma$ and $\zeta$ can represent either uncontrolled inputs or disturbances.

As uncontrolled inputs:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}\alpha\dot{x_1}+\beta\dot{x_2}\\
\delta\dot{x_1}+\epsilon\dot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
 \eta&\theta&\gamma\\
\iota&\kappa&\zeta
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
1
\end{matrix}\right].
$$

As disturbances:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}\alpha\dot{x_1}+\beta\dot{x_2}\\
\delta\dot{x_1}+\epsilon\dot{x_2}\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
 \eta&\theta\\
\iota&\kappa
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{matrix}\right]+
\left[\begin{matrix}
\gamma\\
\zeta
\end{matrix}\right].
$$

Creating the state $s=[s_1\;s_2\;s_3\;s_4]^T=[x_1\;\dot{x_1}\;x_2\;\dot{x_2}]^T$:

$$\dot{s}
=
\dot{\left[\begin{matrix}s_1\\ s_2\\ s_3\\ s_4\end{matrix}\right]}
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
0&1&0&0\\ 
0&\alpha&0&\beta\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&\delta&0&\epsilon
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}s_1\\ s_2\\ s_3\\ s_4\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
0&0\\
\eta&\theta\\
0&0\\
\iota&\kappa
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{matrix}\right]
+
\left[\begin{matrix}
0\\
\gamma\\
0\\
\zeta
\end{matrix}\right].
$$

Depending on your system, you can design a controller that rejects those disturbances; the presence of integrators in the system can help remove steady-state errors.

Comment: Thank you. Is this generally the way computed torque control is done? I am wondering if it would be possible to transform this into a second order state space by representing x1 and x2 in a single vector q = [x1;x2]?

Comment: In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MV-xBPP3H2k, you can see that a combination of feedfoward and PID can be used to control using the torque as input.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
a \, \ddot{x}_1 + b \, \ddot{x}_2 + c \,\dot{x_1} + d \,\dot{x_2} + e &= u_1 \tag{1} \\
f \, \ddot{x}_1 + g \, \ddot{x}_2 + h \,\dot{x_1} + i \,\dot{x_2} + j &= u_2 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Let's write Eq(1) without $\ddot{x}_2$, hence:
$$
\begin{align}
a \, \ddot{x}_1 + b \, \Big[\frac{u_2-f \, \ddot{x}_1 - h \,\dot{x}_1 - i \,\dot{x}_2 - j}{g}\Big] + c \,\dot{x}_1 + d \,\dot{x}_2 + e &= u_1 \\
\left[a-\frac{bf}{g} \right] \, \ddot{x}_1 +  \, \frac{b}{g}u_2 - \frac{bh}{g} \,\dot{x}_1 - \frac{bi}{g} \,\dot{x}_2 - \frac{b}{g}j + c \,\dot{x}_1 + d \,\dot{x}_2 + e &= u_1 \\
%
\left[a-\frac{bf}{g} \right] \, \ddot{x}_1  = u_1 -  \, \frac{b}{g}u_2 + \frac{bh}{g} \,\dot{x}_1 + \frac{bi}{g} \,\dot{x}_2 + \frac{b}{g}j - c \,\dot{x}_1 - d \,\dot{x}_2 - &e \\
%
\ddot{x}_1  = \left[\frac{g}{(ag-bf)} \right] \left[u_1 -  \, \frac{b}{g}u_2 + \frac{bh}{g} \,\dot{x}_1 + \frac{bi}{g} \,\dot{x}_2 + \frac{b}{g}j - c \,\dot{x}_1 - d \,\dot{x}_2 - e\right]  \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Now we do same procedure which is eliminating $\ddot{x}_1$ from Eq(2) hence,
$$
\begin{align}
f \, \Big[\frac{u_1- b \, \ddot{x}_2 - c \,\dot{x_1} - d \,\dot{x_2} - e}{a}\Big] + g \, \ddot{x}_2 + h \,\dot{x_1} + i \,\dot{x_2} + j &= u_2 \\
%
\Big[ g - \frac{fb}{a}\Big] \ddot{x}_2 +  \frac{f}{a} u_1 - \frac{fc}{a} \,\dot{x_1} - \frac{fd}{a} \,\dot{x_2} - \frac{fe}{a} + h \,\dot{x_1} + i \,\dot{x_2} + j &= u_2 \\
%
\Big[ g - \frac{fb}{a}\Big] \ddot{x}_2  = u_2 -  \frac{f}{a} u_1 + \frac{fc}{a} \,\dot{x_1} + \frac{fd}{a} \,\dot{x_2} + \frac{fe}{a} - h \,\dot{x_1} - i \,\dot{x_2} - j \\
%
\ddot{x}_2  = \left[\frac{a}{(ag-bf)} \right] \left[ u_2 -  \frac{f}{a} u_1 + \frac{fc}{a} \,\dot{x_1} + \frac{fd}{a} \,\dot{x_2} + \frac{fe}{a} - h \,\dot{x_1} - i \,\dot{x_2} - j \right] \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Now let $y_1=x_1, y_2=\dot{x}_1, y_3=x_2, y_4=\dot{x}_2$, hence:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{y}_1 &= y_2 \\
\dot{y}_2 &= \left[\frac{g}{(ag-bf)} \right] \left[u_1 -  \, \frac{b}{g}u_2 + \Big[\frac{bh-cg}{g}\Big] \,y_2 + \Big[\frac{bi-dg}{g} \Big] \,y_4 + \frac{bj-eg}{g}\right] \\
\dot{y}_3 &= y_4 \\
\dot{y}_4 &= \left[\frac{a}{(ag-bf)} \right] \left[ u_2 -  \frac{f}{a} u_1 + \Big[\frac{fc-ha}{a} \,\Big] y_2 + \Big[\frac{fd-ia}{a}\Big] \,y_4 + \frac{fe-aj}{a}  \right]
\end{align}
$$

where $ag\neq bf$. You can proceed from here.

Answer (score -1):

Before the question can be answered with mathematical terms, a bit meta knowledge may help to understand the thought system. The goal of creating a state space formula for robotics problems is a typical application of the matlab software. The students are educated how to use a commercial software package for describing real world problems.

With this pre-knowledge in mind it is much easier to identify the correct answer. It was given in the internet already under the URL https://in.mathworks.com/help/control/getstart/linear-lti-models.html The website explains, how to use the famous mathematical software for creating a state space model for a torgue control. What is provided too, is how to create the differential equations and transform them into the matrix notation.

Comment: Students are educated on such easy equations to write them out by hand and learn the method, **then** use software. I don’t know of any good university that would teach students to write a state space model in Matlab, this isn’t a helpful answer on the method on how to write in state space methodology, coming from a poor basis to suggest that universities teach only to use commercial software, particularly for such a simple example.